# syntax to check service status in remote linux machine through powershell

Tags: linux, powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to check the service status of a Remote Linux Machine from a windows machine using powershell. Can anyone please tell if this is possible. If yes, how?

Comment: Just use `ssh`, e.g. `ssh you@remote.host 'systemctl status servicename'` (I don't know the exact syntax for ssh in powershell, so that is how I would do it from `cmd.exe` -- should be the same)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can see status of your desired service from windows powershell.

Use the following command to See the status or execute any other linux command.

```
& 'C:\Program Files\OpenSSH\ssh.exe' user@remote_host -i PATH_OF_CERT "
Systemctl status Server_name
"
```

you can execute more commands after systemctl command under the "" (Inverted commas).